Jetpack navigation and action Intents
I work with Health Connect. And this API require include to AndroidManifet androidx.health.ACTION_SHOW_PERMISSIONS_RATIONALE. I also use Jetpack Navigation and write deeplinks for application. The deeplink tag have action properties, and I wait that I set my fragment in navigation xml deeplink tag with action androidx.health.ACTION_SHOW_PERMISSIONS_RATIONALE and application open this fragment when I will start application with this action. But that isn't true. I need a help, because documentation not describe this option normally. Who came across that?
